# how to list long form on page with mvc bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I mean form with many fields, MVC bootstrap nicely do a form for editing or creating new data vertically 
but listing it's just very long horizontal spread.
Is there a way to generate a list vertically for instance?
so it is not necessary to scroll to the right to see the end?
I'm talking about this below section, what to do if I have those items a lot?
Sorry I'm new to MVC bootstrap so maybe it's basic question but is the a way to mock up pages in MVC to make it easier formatting on page?
thanks

```
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Address List</strong>
        </div>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
                </th>
              </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry yest I removed that div it was left over from what I pasted didnb't want  put too many code here.  Question I have is when using scafolding it work good for creating and editing but for listing I got horizontal representation of each record which may be very long so scrolling to the right is required. What is the proper way to display long records on page. thanks

Comment: Bootstrap offers many ways to layout your forms. Have you tried any of [these](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a little html to do the layout. instead of using tables with lots of columns, i can think of a basic div method, as div by default will layout vertically.

```
<div>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
</div>
<div>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street)
</div>
<div>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
</div>
```